# Index ALWAYS Out of Range in VBA after using WorksheetFunction.Frequency

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, variant

I am trying to bin a large amount of data (up to one million entries) into ~60 bins for use with some data analysis that will eventually be fed into a histogram. The problem is that when I use the code below:

```
Dim myBinnedData As Variant
myBinnedData = Application.WorksheetFunction.Frequency(myData,myBins)
```

'I had to Dim myBinnedData this way becuase otherwise I get an error saying it can't assign to an array

I can never access myBinnedData through the use of an index. The only way I have been able to get the data is through a For Each loop, but before I process each point I need the first and last element in myBinnedData. Everything works fine in the For Each loop, but anytime I try indexing (i.e. data = myBinnedData(0)) I get the Index Out of Range error no matter the index number. I have checked the type using TypeName and it was Variant().

So the question is, what is the correct way to index an array that is created by the WorksheetFunction.Frequency function?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: frequency outputs seem to be two dimensional (1 to x, 1 to 1), try `debug.print myBinnedData(1,1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`frequency` returns a 2-dimensional array (but the 2nd dimension is, as far as I see, only from 1 to 1).
Try

```
  Debug.print lbound(myBinnedData, 1),  ubound(myBinnedData, 1)
  Debug.print lbound(myBinnedData, 2),  ubound(myBinnedData, 2)
```

The first line should give you 1 as lower bound and the size of `myBins`+ 1 as upper bound.
The second line shoud give you 1 as lower and upper bound.
To loop over your data, use

```
dim i as integer
for i = lbound(myBinnedData, 1) to ubound(myBinnedData, 1)
    Debug.print myBinnedData(i, 1)
next i
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That did it!

Answer (score 0):

As Zerk mentioned in the comments, and FunThomas answered, the Frequency function returns a 2D array, so I was able to index it using myBinnedData(index,1). I thought I had already tried that but I guess not! Thanks for the help!

I never tried the answer provided by Nikolaos because I don't call any data from my Excel sheet, I only print to it. The myData and myBins arrays are created in the VBA code.